# Possible to enable multiple endpoint with wsdualhttpbinding + webhttpbinding?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm developing a service app that can allow IoT devices that are connected to server, transfer string data to client through WCF (I have to do this in c# only). I was able to do that by writing a self hosted service using endpoint with wsdualhttpbinding. Now i'd like to add another endpoint to the same service with webhttpbinding to make use of REST features. Is it possible? Appreciate if you can point me to example that do what I mentioned above. Been googling for hours and couldn't find an example that enable wsdualhttpbinding and webhttpbinding together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up answering my own question again. I managed to enable both end point wsdualhttpbinding and webhttpbinding and self-hosted it.

Here are the codes shows how i enable both end points at the console.

```
WebServiceHost host1 = new WebServiceHost(typeof(REST), new Uri("http://localhost:8090/"));
host1.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IREST), new WebHttpBinding(), "rest");
host1.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { HelpEnabled = true });
host1.Open();

ServiceHost host2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(SOAP), new Uri("http://10.121.72.214:8090/soap"));
host2.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISOAP), new WSDualHttpBinding(), "");
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host2.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (smb == null)
{
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host2.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    host2.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
}

host2.Open();

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
Console.WriteLine("Host is opened.");
Console.ReadKey();
host1.Close();
host2.Close();
```

So when i type in http://localhost:8090/rest and http://localhost:8090/soap in the browser. I'm able to see the help page for REST and the SOAP(WSDualHttpBinding) services. I also confirm it can callback method on client side successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please you can simply add webhttpbinding like this

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding 
        allowCookies="Boolean"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="Boolean"
        closeTimeout="TimeSpan"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildCard/Exact/WeakWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="integer"
        maxBufferSize="integer"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="Integer"
        name="string"
        openTimeout="TimeSpan" 
        proxyAddress="URI"
        receiveTimeout="TimeSpan"
        sendTimeout="TimeSpan"
                transferMode="Buffered/Streamed/StreamedRequest/StreamedResponse"
        useDefaultWebProxy="Boolean">

writeEncoding="UnicodeFffeTextEncoding/Utf16TextEncoding/Utf8TextEncoding"
        <security mode="None/Transport/TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType = 
                 "Basic/Certificate/Digest/None/Ntlm/Windows"
                  proxyCredentialType="Basic/Digest/None/Ntlm/Windows"
                  realm="string" />
        </security>
       <readerQuotas             maxArrayLength="Integer"            maxBytesPerRead="Integer"            maxDepth="Integer"             maxNameTableCharCount="Integer"                     maxStringContentLength="Integer" />
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

you can also refer to this site for more information
https://chsakell.com/2013/09/14/wcf-self-hosting-multiple-bindings/

Comment: What about wsdualhttpbinding? Example provided is on nettcp and basichttp instead.